# Mac Os Monterey Downgrade from php 7.3 to 7.2

Tags: php, macos

Hello guys I want to downgrade from PHP7.3 to 7.2 but after installing **PHP 7.2** with
`brew install php@7.2`
and unlinking **PHP 7.3** with `brew unlink php@7.3` the problem that I have is when I relink **PHP 7.2** with `brew link php@7.2` it goes back to the **7.3** version has anyone ever faced this problem, the project that I am working with requires **PHP 7.2**?

Update: This problem is still not fixed, i still can't get the PHP version to go down from 7.3 to 7,2

Comment: and how exactly you're relinking php 7.2 ? Which command

Comment: brew link php@7.2